# Create file from byte array without saving to file directory

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am working on an Android project where I have a PDF file as byte array. My goal is to render this PDF file and show to user in my application (without calling any other third-party PDF viewer).

For security reasons, even temporarily, I am not allowed to create file in phone directory.

Android 5.0, came with a `PdfRenderer` library where you pass `FileDescriptor`, but I can't use it. Is there any way to achieve this?

EDIT:

```
@Deprecated
public static ParcelFileDescriptor fromData(byte[] data, String name) throws IOException {
    if (data == null) return null;
    MemoryFile file = new MemoryFile(name, data.length);
    if (data.length > 0) {
        file.writeBytes(data, 0, 0, data.length);
    }
    file.deactivate();
    FileDescriptor fd = file.getFileDescriptor();
    return fd != null ? new ParcelFileDescriptor(fd) : null;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Technically, Android 5.0 came with a `PdfRenderer` class where you pass a `ParcelFileDescriptor`. In theory, you could create a `ParcelFileDescriptor` pipe and feed it bytes from RAM. However, the `getSeekableFileDescriptor()` reference in the code sample suggests that `PdfRenderer` needs a seekable stream from the `ParcelFileDescriptor`, which AFAIK eliminates all pipe options. You are going to have to find a third-party library that supports input from byte arrays, and lacking that, you are out of luck.

Comment: I looked at `ParcelFileDescriptor` class and it has a method called `fromData`. It is deprecated right now, but do you think this would help me to achieve my goal? I will add this method to my code now.

Comment: Well, that method is deprecated and hidden, so it is not necessarily going to be reliable. You also can't just copy the code, as `getFileDescriptor()` on `MemoryFile` itself is hidden. I also don't know if it will give you a seekable result.

Comment: Yes they are hidden. I was looking for ways to use hidden methods, but as you said it wouldn't be a good practice. Thanks